# Systemd user session and scope

Tags: linux, systemd

When I start my systemd system and login to it, I see 2 user sessions: `c1 for user gdm` and `c2 for my user`. I see 2 slices `(user@120.slice and user@1000.slice)` and 2 scopes `(session-c1.scope and session-c2.scope)`. Several programs or deamons reside in `user@.slice`, others in `session-c*.scope`.

I don't understand and cannot find in documentation why there are 2 (and not 1) sessions in system? And why do several programs reside in `user@.slice` and others in `session-c*.scope`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 sessions because there are 2 users: you and gdm.

session scopes are what is running per 'session' (per login), but user slices are what is running per user (regardless of the number of logins).